# Benchmarking GPU ops in Tensorflow Graphs

Tags: tensorflow, benchmarking

The benchmarking tool https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/benchmark

only profiles ops for CPU. Is there a similar tool for profiling GPU ops or what changes can be made in the benchmarking tool above to get GPU utilization information?

Note: I already have a model and I just need to get the ops profiles for the GraphDef.

Comment: the bare GPU profiler is [nvprof](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html) but that unfortunately does not give you the information about where in your graph the time is spent

Comment: I am now doing it from inside my training code using timeline. but it creates a json file for every step. Can I just write to file in append mode and the combined json will be valid for opening in chrome. Also saw somewhere size of chrome trace limit is 300Mb. Then what is the best way to get the ops resource utilization stats